# Codeigniter Session Values Not Persisting

Tags: session, codeigniter

**ANSWERED: I needed to "unserialize" my session variables in order use then.  Ugh.

$eventTypeID = unserialize($this->session->userdata('eventtypeID'));

---

I realize this is a belabored topic, but being new to CI, I’ve read thru most of the docs, but I must be overlooking something when it comes to correctly setting/getting sessions.

I’ve followed the configurations found in this post and can confirm that FF is storing a cookie:  http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/178904/

The way my app is set up, users select values from 2 dropdowns, those values are then put into session variables and a new view is called.  From within the new view I need to be able to access the session variables and pass them along to query my db.  As it currently stands, when I view the query, no session values are being sent to it.

All assistance is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

***EDITED BELOW: Seems the setting of session variables (array) is not occuring.***

Here’s my code for setting:

```
public function goSearch(){
            if( !empty( $_POST ) ) {
                $this->load->library('session');                
                $searchData = array(
                   'eventtypeID'  => serialize($this->input->post('pEventType')),
                   'venuecityID'  => serialize($this->input->post('pVenueCity'))                   
               );


     $this->session->set_userdata($searchData);  /*ERROR: Nothing is being set.  I've done print_r on $searchData, which returns values, but if I do:

$test = $this->session->set_userdata($searchData);  
Print_r($test);

Nothing is returned */

                  $this->_displayPublicPage('search', NULL);

               }
            }
```

Here’s my function for getting to pass to the query:

```
public function readEvents(){
        $eventTypeID = $this->session->userdata(‘eventtypeID’);
        $venueCityID = $this->session->userdata(‘venuecityID’);
        echo json_encode($this->event_model->getSearchEvents($eventTypeID, $venueCityID));
      }
```

Here’s my query in my model:

```
public function getSearchEvents($eventTypeID, $venueCityID){           
        $eventTypeID = intval($eventTypeID);
        $venueCityID = intval($venueCityID);

        $this->db->select('*');         
        $this->db->where('event_status =', 'A');
        $this->db->where('eventtype.eventtype_id =', $eventTypeID);
        $this->db->where('city.city_id =', $venueCityID);
        $this->db->join('eventtype', 'event.fk_eventtype_id = eventtype.eventtype_id');
        $this->db->join('venue', 'event.fk_venue_id = venue.venue_id'); 
        $this->db->join('city', 'venue.fk_city_id = city.city_id'); 
        $this->db->join('tickets', 'event.event_id = tickets.fk_event_id'); 
        $this->db->from('event');

       $this->db->_compile_select();     
        $q = $this->db->get();
       echo $this->db->last_query();                
        if( $q->num_rows() > 0 ) {
            return $q->result();
        } else {
            return array();
        }

   }
```

Comment: Have you loaded your session class?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using cookies to store your session data, you must reload page after set_userdata(). That's because cookies are sent within http header.

There's no need to use sessions when all you want is to pass variable between controller and a model or a view, anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using Ajax/Jquerry-Datatables in the view I submit to.  The problem is I need to load up a bunch of data before the datatables render, and the easiest way I found to ensure I had what I need was to put items into the session.

Comment: Switching to sessions in database should fix the problem. Saving Session Data to a Database @ http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Thanks.  Is there anything wrong with using PHP's native sessions? Aside from operating outside of the CI framework, I was curious if issues may occur?

Comment: Scratch that...while I can set the sessions, once I go to retrieve them, I get an error: Undefined variable: _SESSION

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't unserializing my data once passed across.  Ugh.  Works now.